# how to get mac share folder path on iOS

Tags: ios, macos, openssh

I'm working on an app,now i used openssh find and get access to my mac's file system,I can access every folder at my app.That dangerous for my computer,I want to know is there any way I can only get the shared folder at my app,instead every folder.Just like use mac to connect other people's share folder,only get the share folder.what should i do,and i'm thinking get the share folder path and use it as an argument,is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSharedPublicDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Playlist"];
```

if you want path of Documents directory replace first line by this

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: sorry,that's not what I want to know,thank you anyway.I want know the shared file directory at mac,not iOS device.Just like use finder to connect other people's share folder,only show the shared file directory,and show you the list of shared folder.I config some share folder at system preference,I want to know the share folder directory

Comment: sorry,seems you are kind right,I create a mac project and used this method,it seem work,but i can only get the public folder,how can i get other share folder?